# Can't get a value from DataGridView to another form

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable

I have a `form` that pops up separately from the main one. It has a `DataGridView` on it which shows all urls the user has visited. All the urls are saved in a list of strings, then transformed to `DataTable` and then I put the values into `DataGridView`. I can see the table with urls.

I wanted to enable doubleclicking on the cell, so that if user doubleclicks on it, he will be transformed to back that url.

I got an error when selecting a row (clicking on url) and and parsing it to string. Seems like it is empty as page is not loading

```
private DataTable ConvertListToDataTable(List<string> l)
    {
        table.Columns.Add("urls");
        int i = 0;
        foreach(string s in l)
        {
            table.Rows.Add();
            table.Rows[i].SetField("urls", s);
            i++;
        }
        return table;
    }
public void pageload(List<string> list)
    {
        table = ConvertListToDataTable(list);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellContentDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 form = new Form1();
        form.pageInput.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows.ToString();
        string input = form.pageInput.Text;
        form.loadPage(input);
    }
```

I tried to change the `DataGridView` `SelectionMode` to **FullRowSelect**, **CellSelect** and **RowHeaderSelect** but it doesn't change anything. Tried to change the double clicking for cells and rows. I also tried to put a `textBox` on the form for debugging purposes. So when I assigned:

```
textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows.ToString()
```

all I get is the `Windows.Forms.DataGridViewSelectedCellCollection`, so it is definitely empty.

The question is how can I get that url value back if `ToString()` is not working? Thanks for the help.

Comment: isn't that `CellContentDoubleClick` will set the `double-clicked cell` in `edit mode`?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: @King Not quiet sure what are you talking about but currently the edit mode is *EditOnKeyStrokeOrF2*. Shall I change it to EditProgrammatically?

Comment: @Messerschmitt I can set the current cell in edit mode with a `double-click`, that's a normal behavior. Although it may not really like a `double-click`, even when you first click on the cell, then just make another click on it and it will be set in edit mode.

Comment: @Brian, the message says: UriFormatException was unhandled. Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined. I got this error when the url string it empty which I probably end up with when calling dataGridView.SelectedRows.ToString()

Comment: @KingKing, I didn't add the columns and rows manually, I insert those programmatically. Probably that's an issue as well. Let me check

Answer (score 0):

If it is a collection, you have to treat each element inside the collection invididually otherwise .ToString() just give you back the text of the selectedRows in the metadata which is DataGridViewSelectedCellCollection.

try something like,

```
foreach(elementType i in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
{
   //do something you want here such as TextBox.Text = TextBox.Text + i.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried to implement this but now I got *DataGridViewRow {Index=0}* displayed in the textbox and still getting an error when loading the page. Well, because it's not a valid url.

Comment: Does dataGridView contain urls? Sounds like there is no single row that contains any url

Comment: Yep, the dataGridView is just a table that shows visited urls. Well, at least those urls are showing up in the table but when I double click at any row, it seems like the row doesn't have anything in it.

Comment: if not the selectedrows then try grab all the rows and see if there is any url in them if there really is url shown in the gridview

Comment: Tried it. It's empty :(

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want/need is something more like this:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{      
    string URL = "";
    if (dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value != null)
    {  
        //get the URL from the cell that you double-clicked on
        URL = dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
    }
    else
        return;

    //put your code to launch the URL in a browser here        
}
```

Another option is to use the MouseDoubleClick event like this:

```
private void dataGridView1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    //this will allow us to find out where we clicked in the datagridview
    DataGridView.HitTestInfo hti = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);

    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && hti.Type == DataGridViewHitTestType.Cell)
    {
        string URL = "";
        if (dataGridView1[hti.ColumnIndex, hti.RowIndex].Value != null)
        {
            //get the URL from the cell that you double-clicked on
            URL = dataGridView1[hti.ColumnIndex, hti.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
        }
        else

            return;
        //put your code to launch the URL in a browser here 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, probably the event you want is `CellDoubleClick()` not `CellContentDoubleClick()`

Then do this:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    //Makes sure that a valid cell was double clicked.
    if (e.ColumnIndex > -1 && e.RowIndex > -1)
    {
        Form1 form = new Form1();
        form.pageInput.Text = dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
        string input = form.pageInput.Text;
        form.loadPage(input);
    }
}
```

Let me know if this works!

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't make any difference